# Purchasing more than one item via Add To cart paypal

Tags: php, forms, paypal

I'm working on purchasing more than one item via "Add to Cart" paypal button. Here is my code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

          <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"/>

          <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller_1360303883_biz@gmail.com"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>

          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="$<?php  echo $price1 ?>"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="1.75"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1"/>

          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="$<?php  echo $price2 ?>"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="shipping_2" value="2.50"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1"/>

          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Item Name 3"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="$<?php  echo $price3 ?>"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="shipping_3" value="2.50"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="quantity_3" value="2"/>
```

```
       <!-- <input type="submit" value="PayPal"/> -->

        </form>
```

By using above code i; getting the error:

"You have entered an invalid quantity value. A quantity value must be an integer greater than or equal to one."

I've searched it and try the suggestions but none of them worked.
Any help would be great!

Comment: This is a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18804908/how-to-set-a-quantity-of-zero-in-paypal-cart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are using sandbox and in form you are putting  form action of paypal insetead sandbox of paypal

Comment: i made a horrible mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that the value shouldn't have a dollar sign prepended to it. You aren't submitting a number greater than or equal to one with that in there.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I use a semicolon at the of each PHP statement.

```
<?php

$price1=12.99;
$price2=13.49;
$price3=17.99;

?>

<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="<?php  echo $price1; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="<?php  echo $price2; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="<?php  echo $price3; ?>"/>
```

You might want to verify that the $prices you have are valid.