# How to set a quantity of ZERO in paypal cart

Tags: paypal

Whenever I try to order something from my own PayPal form, all of the values must be above 0.  How can I make it only order one item while another is set to zero

The error message: You have entered an invalid quantity value. A quantity value must be an integer greater than or equal to one.

Sample code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3GH3K/)

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
<input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
<input name="business" type="hidden" value="test@example.com" />

Italian on Wheat Bread
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="6.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Italian on Wheat Bread" />
<input type="number" name="quantity_1" value="0" />
<br />
Turkey on White Bread
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="6.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Turkey on White Bread" /> 
<input type="number" name="quantity_2" value="0" /> 
<br />
Vegetarian on Wheat Bread
<input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="6.00" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Vegetarian on Wheat Bread" /> 
<input type="number" name="quantity_3" value="1" /> 
<br />

<input type=submit />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

PayPal forms require that the integer be greater than zero. The order form does not have the option to have a 0 quantity of an item. Having a zero quantity means that the item is not in the cart.

[PayPal Form Basics](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/formbasics/)